# Получение имени текущего (залогиненного) пользователя AD

Tags: php, auth

Развернут CentOS, PHP (с библиотекой php-ldap), Apache, MySQL. Создан сайт.
Необходимо получить доменное имя пользователя, открывшего вэб-страницу и через скрипт внести данные в БД. Скрипт написан, дело за малым.
Вариант `$_SERVER['auth_user']` не работает, я так понял, потому что у меня не IIS.

Comment: В общем случае браузер как бы не обязан передавать подобного рода данные...

Comment: Попробуйте apache mod_auth_sspi https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ModAuthSSPI

Comment: Путь ваш лежит за тридевять земель в тридесятое царство. По пути придется сносить пять пар железных сапог и сгрызть десять железных хлебов... А так то гуглите Apache SSO

Answer (score 1):

Простого ответа на ваш вопрос, к сожалению, не существует.

По факту вам придется тем, либо иным образом настроить сквозную авторизацию пользователей на вашем контроллере домена  через Apache.

Существует множество способов это сделать. Ни один из них не является простым в исполнении. Не зная политик вашего домена даже нельзя сказать, какой из них заработает и, главное, продолжит работать со временем. (С другой стороны, может вообще сразу взлетит и не будет доставлять проблем, так тоже бывает)

В общем случае такая штука называется SSO (Single Sign-On). В случае Apache гуглите по словам `Apache SSO`.

Кошерный путь - использовать чистый `mod_auth_kerb` ([пример](http://docs.ipi-manager.ru/AdministratorGuide/Configuration/ActiveDirectory/Apache/))

Можно попытаться через kerberos + samba ([пример](https://gist.github.com/potatoqualitee/6cda9383e3cef4954f073a6da7e7818d))

Еще есть дедушка mod_ntlm, говорят у кого-то получается с ним ([пример](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/))

Через kerberos + mod_authnz_ldap тоже делают ([пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/274931/))

Comment: Спасибо за нужные советы! Дело в том, что в моём вэб приложении идет электронная регистрация заявок и необходимо логировать автора заявки и закрывающего её.